# Plumbing water line and drain schedule

Tags: garage, planning, planning-permission, permitting

I want to build a detached garage. I submitted plans to the city for a permit and they came back telling me they need to see the "plumbing water line and drain schedule" because I would like to have a sink in the garage. I am searching the web to no avail... I have no idea what they mean by that. Can someone show me an example...pretty please?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Not knowing what a "schedule" is suggests that you'll need to hire someone who does.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe schedule is a standard way of specify the thickness of the wall of the pipes.  There is code that requires minimum schedule pipe and approved materials for drains and pipes.  Code varies by location.  They probably want you to specify something like

```
MIN. SCH 40 ABS 3" DRAIN PIPE
```

On your plans.  You could also ask the city to show you some example plans.  Or even go in to the office in person and ask about meeting with your plans reviewer, if nothing else.  In my city they encourage you to do this before submitting them.